# CSS border above and below but not full width

Tags: css, styling, text-styling, blockquote

I am attempting to define a global style for block-quotes on a site I'm working on.

The goal is to style the block-quotes so that they appear similar to the image below.  I would like to avoid having to modify the DOM structure.

Using pseudo-classes I would like to display horizontal parallel borders above and below the element but the lines should only be half as wide as the element itself and centered horizontally.

[image: Mockup of blockquote]

This is as far as I've gotten so far, but the lines are not centered properly.

```css
blockquote {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    font-size: 15px;
}

blockquote:before {
    content: '\A';
    height: 1px;
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    top: -8px;
}

blockquote:after {
    content: '\A';
    height: 1px;
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    bottom: -8px;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  Neque porro quisquam e porro quisquest qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit<br />
 est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet rem ipsum quia 
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the width is fixed you can use negative margin-left to center element. In your case `margin-left: -20%;`:

```css
blockquote { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    font-size: 15px;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;         /* <-- put left edge in the middle */
    margin-left: -20%; /* <-- shift to the left by half of the width */
    width: 40%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000;
}
blockquote:after {
    top: inherit;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  Neque porro quisquam e porro quisquest qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit<br>
 est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet rem ipsum quia 
</blockquote>
```

Comment: This is sweet, add a quick margin-top/margin-bottom of like -10px to the before and after and he has his spacing too, +1 for learning something today :)

Comment: Yes margin-top/bottom or negative top/bottom values to adjust vertical spacing.

Comment: @dcc This can be simplified a little using only one pseudo element and border top/bottom : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/krnorhwp/

Comment: @web-tiki In this case I think this pseudo element will overlay content.

Comment: @dfsq no, as I used the before pseudo element it is behind the content of the blockquote. you can see that by inspecting with dev tools.